# Almost Everywhere Convergence for Numerical Sequences

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

When we define almost everywhere convergence, we usually define it only for convergence of
sequence of functions. Yet, I was wondering if there was some sort of analogue definitions for numerical sequences. For example, we have that:

**(Metric Convergence)** A sequence $x_n$ is said to converge to $x$ in the metric space $(X,d)$ if $d(x_n,x) \to 0$.

The definition I was thinking was something that somehow extended to the notion of a.e. convergence of functions, the same way metric convergence does. For example:

**(a.e Metric Convergence)** A sequence $x_n$ converges a.e. to $x$ in the metric measurable space $(X,\mathcal F, \mu, d)$ if there exists a measurable set $A \subset X$ such that
$\mu(A) = 0$ and:

i) If $x \in A^c$ and $x_n \cap A^c$ converges in metric to $x \cap A^c$;

ii) Or, if $x \in A$, and $(x_n)\subset A$.

Hence, if $\{x_n\} \cap A^c = \varnothing$, we say that it does not converge if $x \in A$.

I came up with the above definition, and I was wondering if there exists anything of the sort.

Comment: What does $x_n \cap A^{c}$ mean?

Comment: I don't follow your notion, but you can have a look at the paper https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1995-347-05/S0002-9947-1995-1260176-6/home.html, which essentially goes along what you want.

Comment: This isn’t a useful extension of “almost everywhere,” since that is explicitly about which parameters of the sequence of functions lead to convergence. You can define other convergences. The “almost everywhere” is not about the values $n.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So do let us know which ones.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, it’s abuse of notation for “consider only the points in the sequence where $x_n\in A^c$.